# Change text inside html5 audio player - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, audio, cordova, html5-audio

I am using cordova 3 and building app for **ios**.
I'm streaming audio channel using html5 audio player. Now as it has no stop function, so I had to change the source of the player to an invalid stream address to stop player both streaming and loading.

Before this `stop` mechanism, when I use the `pause` functionality the player kept loading the stream. That unacceptable. Because I don't want the user to waste bandwidth when the player is in `pause mode`. So the idea worked of that invalid addres. But when I set the address the player shows

> cannot play audio file

I want to show

> please select a channel

Is there any way to replace this text as I want to?? I tried

```
document.getElementById('myaudio').text="Plese select a channel";
```

It's not working. Player still shows `cannot play audio file`

How to achive this functionality?

Comment: `text` is not a property on any DOM element I'm aware of. Did you mean `innerText`?

Comment: @RGraham I'm not sure what is that. Player text changes into "loading" "streaming" etc based on player status. I tried to change the innerText, not working either.